# ASP.NET MVC handling complex errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

My view has extremely complex presentation logic based on many factors. In our controller we calculate various presentation settings, like ShowSection1, ShowSubSection2A, etc. and then send them to the view with ViewData. There are about 30 of these settings.

The problem is when a user clicks Submit, our action is called and then does complex business logic which can throw various exceptions. I want to display the error to the user AND keep the page exactly as it was before they submitted, so they don't have to re-enter data. But from the Submit action, I can't do a Return View to the same view because all the ViewData is gone, and hence all the presentation settings. And if I store the settings in the model itself, they're lost because they don't correspond to fields that can be bound back to the model. I must be missing something. Is Web API the only way?

Comment: Why don't you handle presentation logic in the view itself? Can't you rebuild the `ViewData` object when the submit fails? Have you tried to validate your view either client-side or make a ajax call and validate it server side then return the result?

Comment: That's the catch22 of MVC for me. We CAN do everything on the client and jQuery but then why even do .NET? And besides, the presentation logic involves calculations based off our request (several hundred fields), a customer profile (about 50 properties), and the user type. So we'd have to bring all that in which is the other catch22 of MVC. There's no ViewState but to do client-side calcs of any complexity you end up building your own viewstate using the model, viewdata, etc.

Comment: Seems like the only answer is to use the TempData object vs the temporary ViewData object to hold all the presentation settings, which include custom field labels that depend on the customer logged in.